# C++ If loop inside a for loop. Limits

Tags: c++, loops, if-statement, for-loop

I have this code.

```
 for(int j=0; j<=n; j++) {
     Xnew2 = j*(Y+R2)/n;
     Ynew2 = pow((((Y+R2)*(Y+R2)) - (Xnew2*Xnew2)), 0.5);
     cout<<"\n("<<Xnew2<<","<<Ynew2<<")"; 
 }
```

I want all the values to be displayed, but I also want to create a limit on the values displayed to make sure that `Ynew2` cannot go any higher than 310 or any less than -310. The Radius is 482.7mm, which is the number the values are currently going to.

How do I do this? I tried putting an `if` loop inside it, but it didn't work and anything else I tried gave me only one value. Any help?

Comment: What did the `if` you put inside the loop look like?

Comment: If Ynew2 <=310 //was just trying to see if i could get one value to work
cout<<"\n("<<Xnew2<<","<<Ynew2<<")";

Comment: `if(Ynew <= 310) cout << ...` should work and prevent values *greater* than 310 from being displayed. Values greater than -310 on the other hand would still show up.

Comment: Where would I finish the loop though? (for the If function) I have code above which is nearly the same that works perfectly, but it has no limits. Just can't seem to fix this one

Comment: Do you want to *exit* the loop immediately if you get a value that's not in the range (-310, 310)?

Comment: Well not exit it as sorts, just want it to display the values with the limits imposed. ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
for(int j=0; j<=n; j++) {
    Xnew2 = j*(Y+R2)/n;
    Ynew2 = pow((((Y+R2)*(Y+R2)) - (Xnew2*Xnew2)), 0.5);

    if(abs(Ynew2) <= 310))
        cout<<"\n("<<Xnew2<<","<<Ynew2<<")"; 
}
```

We use the `abs` function to get the absolute value of the `Ynew2` variable, and compare it against 310. If it's less than or equal to 310, we display the point, otherwise, we don't.

Sidenote: you should avoid using `\n` and use `std::endl` (or just `endl` if you have an appropriate `using` declaration).

Comment: Okay I tried you code. The problem i have is that it only displays 3 values rather than the 10 I ask for (when I declare n as 10). Is this just because there are only 3 values which are not cancelled out by the limits.

Okay, will do, what is the reasoning behind avoiding \n?

Comment: Correct - only three values of `Ynew2` fall within the range [-310, 310], the rest are dropped. The reasoning is that `endl` is the appropriate way to insert a new line (some terminals, for example, might require a `\r\n` instead of a `\n`) and does additional work, including flushing internal buffers, etc.

Comment: Thank you very much, been extremely helpful. Will change the \n. Thanks again!

Comment: How would I then put those results into an equation and generate results for every point? another increment?

Comment: I don't follow? What are you trying to achieve, exactly? Use the results that fall within [-310, 310]?

Comment: We are drawing out the Syastro letter K. Which is like a crecent moon, and the way we thought about doing this was but creating two circles ad calculating the points on the half circles. This is is why we were looking for a way to limit the values so that the two circles joined at the start and end points. Does this part make sense? Difficult to explain. We then needed to use these points to calculate angles of the robot hand that was drawing this letter. Which is the part I meant about using the equations.

Comment: I think that you're going about this the wrong way. It should be fairly trivial to come up with two distinct functions representing arcs which intersect at two points, and look like the shape you want, without having to filter out bad values and the like.

Comment: What way would you suggest ? Because its not just the points on intersection, its the points on the curve as well.

Comment: Rory, as I said, I would have two distinct functions, which generate the required curves. It should be fairly simple; from a cursory examination, it looks like you need the equation of an ellipse.

Answer (score 0):

```
for(int j=0; j<=n; j++)
{
    Xnew2 = j*(Y+R2)/n;
    Ynew2 = pow((((Y+R2)*(Y+R2)) - (Xnew2*Xnew2)), 0.5);
    if (Ynew2 < 310 && Ynew2 > -310)
        cout<<"\n("<<Xnew2<<","<<Ynew2<<")"; 
}
```

Comment: It doesn't seem to show the specified amount of values this way?

Comment: I guess it depends on what you want to happen when the values are outside of the limits that you have placed. What is the behavior you want?

Answer (score 0):

```
   const int YLIMIT = 310;
   for(int j=0; j<=n; j++) {
       Xnew2 = j*(Y+R2)/n;
       int Ynew2Raw = pow((((Y+R2)*(Y+R2)) - (Xnew2*Xnew2)), 0.5);
       int Ysign = Ynew2Raw >= 0 ? 1 : -1;
       int limitedY2 = std::min(abs(Ynew2Raw, YLIMIT));
       Ynew2 = Ysign * limtedY2;

       cout<<"\n("<<Xnew2<<","<<Ynew2<<")"; 
   }
```